# Laravel 5.8 conditionally inserting sql snippet

Tags: php, sql, laravel, db2, odbc

I'm trying to figure out the best way to resolve inserting a conditional sql snippet within a laravel 5.8 application function.

I'm successfully calling a function with a request parameter `$type`.

`$type` coming into this function can be 1,2 or 3 (when 3 I basically want the sql query to perform with nothing in that spot), but currently it successfully returns the query results from below as if nothing is being injected at all. I can dump the $typeCondition based on the selection and it toggles properly, so I know the typeCondition is being set properly but it looks like it's not actually plugging the typeCondition into the query and I get the same results every time, so it seems like maybe this is a syntax issue?

If I run the below version as just `:typeCondition` it errors out and says it's not a valid param call.

What should I do here?

```
public static function gatherReporting($type) {

    if($type ==1){
      $typeCondition = 'AND T1 . parent_id IS NOT NULL';
    }elseif($type ==2){
      $typeCondition = 'AND T1 . parent_id IS NULL';
    }else{
      $typeCondition = '';
    }

    $sql = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM   SCHEMA . TABLE T1
        WHERE ACTIVE = 1
        {:typeCondition}
        INNER JOIN SCHEMA . TABLE2 T2
        ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    ";
    return DB::connection('odbc')->select($sql,  [
                'typeCondition' => $typeCondition
            ]);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried concatenating it as a string? `$sql = "SELECT * FROM SCHEMA . TABLE T1 WHERE ACTIVE = 1" . $typeCondition;`

Comment: I thought about that possiblity but the problem is I will have more to the query after this section for a join

Comment: @LucasArbex I think that would work but as soon as this is working I need to scale it up a little bit

Comment: Why can't you continue concatenating it? Show us an example of how you want it to scale then... :)

Comment: I just made an edit for an example

Comment: Ok, but I still don't understand why can't you concatenate it, like `$sql = "SELECT * FROM SCHEMA . TABLE T1 WHERE ACTIVE = 1" . $typeCondition . "INNER JOIN SCHEMA . TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID";`

Comment: That did work so if you want to make an answer I'll be glad to accept. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for doing that. I have posted an answer. And I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the query as a `string` and concatenate it with your variable. Like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM SCHEMA . TABLE T1 WHERE ACTIVE = 1" . $typeCondition . "INNER JOIN SCHEMA . TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Query Builder to get something clean :

```
$query = Schema::select('*')->where('active', 1);

if ($type === 1) {
    $query->whereNotNull('parent_id');
} elseif ($type === 2) {
    $query->whereNull('parent_id');
}

$data = $query->get();
```

Comment: I want to scale this a bit though and I don't think Query Builder will be conducive to what I want with what I've seen from it's interaction with ODBC in my past